# AsyncStorage.getItem behaviour when key does not exist

Tags: react-native

Skimming the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#getitem), the async/promise behaviour of `AsyncStorage.getItem(key)` in cases where the key does not exist, is not clear to me.

If a key does not exist, should I expect the promise to be resolved with `null` or rejected with an error object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is stating that;

> Function that will be called with a result if found or any error.

This means if the key does not exist result will be `null` since there will be no result to return.

**Sample**

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('text', (error, result) => {
  if(error) console.error('Something went wrong!');
  else if(result) console.log('Getting key was successfull', result);
  else if(result === null) console.log('Key does not exists!');
});
```

Comment: I've just noticed, I missed a key point in my question. I've updated it

Comment: @DacreDenny Updated my answer. I already told that result will be null.

Comment: Thanks, I just reworded the question to hopefully make it more useful for the community